How to make different record `type`s unequal
I am learning PureScript due to not being satisfied (in particular) with TypeScript's type safety of what's called "records" in PS. While doing so I stumble upon the exact same problem in PS, do I miss something?
Given these two types:
type Foo = {a :: Int}
type Bar = {a :: Int}

Comparing them gives no compiler error! So type is more like an alias and isn't actually a type.
"PureScript by Example" uses it exactly to define types though and calls them "records". So I thought: maybe there's confusion and PureScript "records" aren't the records in Haskell-sense. I went searching PS vs Haskell syntax comparision, and lo and behold, it said to be the data from Haskell. Indeed PS hasn't a newtype or data keywords. (actually, apparently there is a separate package Data.Newtype, but, well, it is a separate package; and I'm also not sure how well it'd work for getting rid of type completely in preference of newtype).
I do realize that in Haskell similar code:
data Foo = Foo {a :: Int}
data Bar = Bar {a :: Int}

…will result in Multiple declarations of ‘a’. But it is important: the compiler will error out. There is type-safety, I can't accidentally make different types with same fields or compare different types.
Can't I achieve the same behavior in PureScript?
Steps to reproduce
Build the following PureScript code:
module Main where

import Prelude

import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)

type Foo = {a :: Int}
type Bar = {a :: Int}

foo :: Foo
foo = {a : 1}

bar :: Bar
bar = {a : 1}

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  log $ show $ foo == bar

Expected
A compiler error about foo and bar having different types inside == comparison.
Actual
It compiles successfully.

Yes, PureScript does very much have newtype and data keywords, and they do behave exactly like in Haskell.
newtype Foo = Foo { a :: Int }
newtype Bar = Bar { a :: Int }

Well, almost exactly. Unlike in Haskell, this won't actually cause "double declaration of a", because PureScript, unlike Haskell, has real records. With real fields. Not just globally scoped accessor functions.

But yeah, ⁼¹, the mismatch about the types in case of newtypes is relieving.

The book says Newtypes must define exactly one constructor, and that constructor must take exactly one argument. That means in most cases newtype won't replace type, because like 90% of types have more than one parameter.

Yes, that is absolutely correct. Newtypes are for specifically the situation you described in your question: you have types that are functionally identical, but you don't want them to count as the same type. That's when you wrap them in newtype. Otherwise - if you want multiple parameters or multiple constructors, - use data. Although I would recommend using records for the multiple parameters case instead. They are much more ergonomic than multiparameter constructors.

Omg, I'm sorry, I don't know why but in my experiements neither data nor newtype worked, I honestly spent a lot of time and research on that. And now they just work… ‍♂️ Oh well… I guess that happens, what can I do now… Marking as ✓Accepted, thank you.

Glad I could help. And good luck with your PureScript experiments, it's a very neat and practically useful language.
